# Am not able to send email to last row when a new row is added in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

through my script,i am not able to send email to the last row when there is a new row added ,though it is running showing no error still am not able to send email to last row when added to sheet. Any one pls help me out.
i have the email adress in column 3,name column in column 6.

i tried the above script ,it is running but not able to send email to last row only when a row is added. i want to send mail to last row when a row is added only.I tried i edited the trigger but still not achieveing the result.

Comment: `i tried the above script` Would you please edit your question to include the actual script.  `i edited the trigger` Would you please also describe the trigger type that you are using.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendingEmailsFromSpreadsheetData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  vs.forEach() {
    //codes to assemble email in here
  }
}
```